# Do kindless ancestor queries always return the ancestor first?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, gql

GQL allows Kindless ancestor queries (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/queries#kindless_ancestor_queries) where you can query in one go for both an ancestor and all of its descendants. As far as I can tell the ancestor is always returned first, followed by all the descendants?  However, I can't find anything that confirms this.

So, my question: is it always the case that the ancestor is returned first followed by all of the descendants? And is there any documentation that confirms this point?

The reason for asking is that I can keep my code simpler if I know that the ancestor is always first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation detail that can change in the future. Do not rely upon this ordering as it will most likely lead your code to break in the future.

Comment: Thanks very much, it's useful to have that confirmation.  There is data in the ancestor that I can use distinguish it from the children.  I was just wondering whether there was a rule that would allow me to minimise the processing needed.

Comment: Np.  Out of curiosity, do you want to process the ancestor separately, or do you really want to ignore it?

Comment: We want to obtain the ancestor's data including a field that contains a list of all the children's data.  It's nice to be able to do that all in one query.  Also, I was wondering whether it might be worth writing in the documentation that one shouldn't rely on the fact that the ancestor just happens to be first in the results and that it might not do so in future